# The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type TabMapFragment

Tags: android, fragment, google-play-services

I am new to Android and are currently developing an application that uses tabs, one of the tabs using google maps. On my MacBook the code compiles, but on my desktop-PC it doesn't. I've tried to add the same libraries on both pc`s, but the code only compiles on my Mac. The problem is getChildFragmentManager, that is undefined for the type TabMapFragment.

Snippet from my code :

```
private SupportMapFragment fragment;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    userLoggedIn = ((TabListenerActivity)getActivity()).getUserLoggedIn();
    userList = ((TabListenerActivity)getActivity()).getUserList();
    filter = ((TabListenerActivity)getActivity()).getFilter();
    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager(); //<-- This line is the problem
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
    }
    else{
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

I have tried to replace my android-support-v4.jar in my Facebook SDK
(I'm using support-v4 from the facebook SDK) with a newer version of android-support. I've rebuilded and cleaned project, and used the same google-play-services-lib (and the same Facebook SDK) on both pc`s

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have u tried to clean and rebuild the code? if u have stacktrace can u please write it down

Comment: Yes, im building automatically, and i`ve cleaned my code. My project has errors, I can`t run the application

Comment: Any StackTrace or other Error to based on?

Comment: The error is : The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type TabMapFragment

Comment: are the SDK Versions and Google Play Services the same on the phones?

Comment: Yes, i`m using the same google-play-services lib for both devices

Comment: Try using Gradle.. it should take care of SDK dependencies...

Comment: I solved the problem, I thought i had tried to replace the android-support-v4.jar in the Facebook SDK, but I noticed there was 2x libs folders, and i replaced it in the wrong folder. Too get the latest android-support-v4.jar, download it with the SDK-manager, you will find it in extras/android/support/v4/